# Mass Assignment Vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I have a model `A` such as :

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

I want to remove mass assignment vulnerability on attribute `:name`. So I deleted the line `attr_accessible :name` from this model. This model has no controller, so I didn't write any strong parameters. This model is used in a helper `B.rb` as follows :

`num_users = A.where(:name => "NEW").count`

Do I need to change this line in any way or will this line still work after I have deleted `attr_attributed :name` from my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, this line `num_users = A.where(:name => "NEW").count` works fine with or without using mass-assignment. This is because `where` method do not assign data to a model record.

On the other hand, it is rare to see a question with ruby-on-rails-4 and mass-assignment tags (there are only 7 with both).

This is because Rails 4 remove mass_assignment and replace it with strong_parameters, you can find it at [rails guides upgrade to 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#upgrade).

If the line `attr_accessible :name` is working fine on your rails 4 app. Then you must have the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem at your Gemfile.

There must be a good reason for add the protected_attributes gem to a Rails 4 app. If not, you can remove from the Gemfile do bundle install and remove all the `attr_accessible ...` lines from your model. And also remove the `:without_protection => true` parameter from the model's actions (new, create, create!, update_attributes and update_attributes!, assign_attributes).

If you keep the gem protected_attributes at the Gemfile. Then when you need to update some field which is not `attr_accessible` you must add a parameter `without_protection: true` to the action. This way:

```
A.create({name: 'NEW'}, without_protection: true)
```

And the record will be stored at the db. Otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine, the mass-assignment protection is only when you assign en mass, ie. you assign a lot of attributes all at once (eg. `A.create(params)`) and it is also only when you use the `params` that come into a controller, ie. you won't ever have this problem when doing mass assignment yourself with a hash you created.